# hibernation disabled but :: kernel: PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]

Tags: systemd, hibernate

MATE on Arch with 'Do Nothing' selected for all power options in the power management GUI.

Have run `systemctl disable` on all systemd hibernation and sleep services.

But the journal shows this :

```
Aug 26 15:43:40 asus kernel: PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
Aug 26 15:43:40 asus kernel: PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00058000-0x00058fff]
Aug 26 15:43:40 asus kernel: PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009f000-0x0009ffff]
...
Aug 26 15:43:40 asus kernel: PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfee00fff]
Aug 26 15:43:40 asus kernel: PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee01000-0xfeffffff]
Aug 26 15:43:40 asus kernel: PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xff000000-0xffffffff]
```

Why? What's going on here?

Comment: Did you solve your problem ? Got the same here

Comment: @dev93 Nope. I'm just ignoring it. Be nice to not have to ignore it but we must live on.